# How can I evaluate if an integer or decimal is within a tolerance when the tolerance is provided in a format like ±2?

Tags: vb.net

I have a table of tolerances that can be applied to values in my application.

The tolerances are in the format ±2, ±1, -2/+1 for example, there are many combinations but all either plus/minus the same value or plus one value minus a different value.

I wondered how I can evaluate weather a value is within the tolerance.

For example the value is 100 and the tolerance is ±2, I know the value must be between 98 and 102.

I wanted to avoid having to wrtie an if statement like this:

```
        If toleranceID = 1 Then '±2
            If value < 98 OrElse value > 102 Then
                'Fail
            End If
        ElseIf toleranceID = 2 Then '±1
            If value < 99 OrElse value > 101 Then
                'Fail
            End If
        ElseIf toleranceID = 3 Then '-2/+1
            If value < 98 OrElse value > 101 Then
                'Fail
            End If
        End If
```

As there are alot of different tolerances.

EDIT: I didn't feel as if this question was too broad?

I am just asking if there is a way to do this without having to write a big If Else If statement. Please could you provide me with what information I need to add to this, or a reason why it should be closed. I am more than happy to close it if the reason is fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a sample, I try to use dictionary:

```
Dim Tolerance As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub FrmTest_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Tolerance.Add("+2-1", "-1, 2") '(Tolerance key, tolerance value)
    Tolerance.Add("+1-1", "-1, 1")
    Tolerance.Add("+1-2", "-2, 1")

    MsgBox(CheckTolerance(100, 99, "+2-1"))
End Sub

Private Function CheckTolerance(RefVal As Integer, CheckVal As Integer, UsedTolerance As String) As Boolean
    Dim HighTol As Integer = 0
    Dim LowTol As Integer = 0

    If Not Tolerance.ContainsKey(UsedTolerance) Then
        MsgBox("Your Tolerance Is Invalid")
        Return False
    End If
    Integer.TryParse((Tolerance(UsedTolerance).ToString.Split(",".ToCharArray))(0), LowTol)
    Integer.TryParse((Tolerance(UsedTolerance).ToString.Split(",".ToCharArray))(1), HighTol)
    If CheckVal >= (RefVal + LowTol) And CheckVal <= (RefVal + HighTol) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is Collection?

Comment: Because collection is a class that can store data and key, so in this sample I try to use it

Comment: I see Collection(Of T) but not Collection. Is that what you meant? `Dim Tolerance As New Collection` will not compile.

Comment: No, collection (of T) without index key, I think, but collection is like dictionary class, they have a key that can be accessed to get his item value. This class I take from Microsoft.VisualBasic.collection.

Comment: Is this a custom type? Please provide the necessary Imports.

Comment: Finally found it in the vb namespace. The only way it would be accepted by VS2019 is fully qualified `Dim Tolerance As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()` However the remarks in the MS Docs say "Whenever possible, you should use the generic collections in the System.Collections.Generic namespace instead of a Visual Basic Collection. "

Comment: for the generic namespace, may be dictionary can be used instead

Comment: Yes, but the .Add method is reversed in a .net Dictionary. Please edit your answer to get rid of this old VB6 Collection and used the typed Dictionary(Of T, T)

Comment: Thank you, works great! I had to change the line `If CheckVal >= (RefVal + LowTol) And CheckVal <= (RefVal + HighTol) Then`
to 
`If CheckVal >= (RefVal - LowTol) And CheckVal <= (RefVal + HighTol) Then` but that's all.

Comment: Thank you @Mary as well for reviewing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Load your values into a Dictionary structure and create a function that looks something like this (pseudocode)

Function IsWithinTolerance (value, toleranceKey) Boolean

// get tolerance out of dictionary
 // Tolerance will parse the value and return the +/- values
 var tolerance = getTolerance(key)

Return (value <= tolerance.maxValue 
       And value >= tolerance.minValue)

End Function

Comment: Sorry, wrote this in my phone and not sure how to format

Comment: Also, loading into Dictionary assumes you need them all in memory at once.  Up to you to decide if that is necessary or if you can pull in on demand.